# Passing variable in response.write + nodejs to show progress value

Tags: javascript, node.js, response

I am trying to upload file using ckeditor and uploading the file to s3, I am successfully able to upload the file to s3 and get back the url, however want to show the progress to user in browser iframe.

Using s3 uploader I can get progress with on emitter 'progress'

```
  var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
            uploader.on('progress', function () {
                var percent = ((parseInt(uploader.progressAmount) * 100) / parseInt(uploader.progressTotal)).toFixed(2);

                return callback(null,{type : 'progress', percent: percent, url : null});
            });
```

**s3 upload**

```
s3uploads(fileUrl, function (err, uploadResult) {
  if (err) {
    res.send("error");
  }

  if (uploadResult.type === 'progress') {


    html = "<p>Please wait its uploading to server </p> <p>" + uploadResult.percent + "</p>";
    console.log(html);
    res.write(html);

  } else {
    fileUrl = uploadResult.url;
    res.write("<script type='text/javascript'>\
(function(){var d=document.domain;while (true){try{var A=window.parent.document.domain;break;}catch(e) {};d=d.replace(/.*?(?:\.|$)/,'');if (d.length==0) break;try{document.domain=d;}catch (e){break;}}})();\
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('" + CKEcallback + "','" + fileUrl + "', '" + msg + "');\
</script>");
    res.end();
  }

});
```

The response.write is only showing the first value and when I try to pass the variable uploadResult.percent it ignores the value in response.write however it shows when I do console.log(html)

This answer gives much more clarity what I am trying to do. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45902781/1391499

Comment: what is the meaning of url in 'upload and get the url'? why we need url here.

Comment: Wierd, can you provide live demo?

Comment: @MukulSharma the actual question is below. That is just the process which says the functionality is working perfectly to send the data back to user just its in not taking variable value